# How can I extract only the email body with Python using IMAP?

Tags: python, printing, imap

I am relatively new to programming and to python, but I think I have done ok so far. This is the code I have, and it works fine, except it gets the entire message in MIME format. I only want the text body of unread emails, but I can't quite figure it out how to strip out all of the formatting and header info. If I send a basic email using a smtp python script that I made it works fine, and only prints the body, but if I send the email using outlook it prints a bunch of extra garbage. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
client = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(PopServer)

client.login(USER, PASSWORD)
client.select('INBOX')
status, email_ids = client.search(None, '(UNSEEN SUBJECT "%s")' % PrintSubject)
print email_ids
client.store(email_ids[0].replace(' ',','),'+FLAGS','\Seen')
for email in get_emails(email_ids):
```

get_emails()

```
    def get_emails(email_ids):
        data = []
        for e_id in email_ids[0].split():
            _, response = client.fetch(e_id, '(UID BODY[TEXT])')
            data.append(response[0][1])
        return data
```

Comment: If I recall, the outlook program follows its own standard for email messages (which include some "extra garbage". Try Googling for a definition of it.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for the [`email`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/email.parser.html) package:

> The email package provides a standard parser that understands most email document structures, including MIME documents. You can pass the parser a string or a file object, and the parser will return to you the root Message instance of the object structure. For simple, non-MIME messages the payload of this root object will likely be a string containing the text of the message. For MIME messages, the root object will return True from its is_multipart() method, and the subparts can be accessed via the get_payload() and walk() methods.